# How can I use Quartz library to schedule some task from date X1/Y1/Z1 to date X2/Y2/Z2 at XX:XX every day?

Tags: java, timer, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have been looking for an example of how to use the [Quartz library](http://quartz-scheduler.org) in this particular situation. I have found examples for Quartz 1 but I am using the latest version `2.2.1.`

For example, I wish to schedule an action **every day at 08:00 AM between 01/03/2015 and 25/05/2015**. A plus would be to even add **every day, but the weekends**.

This action could be anything, to simplify lets assume something silly like pinging a server, by calling the method `ping()`.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will do what you want *except it will execute until end of may*.

```
0 0 8 ? 3,4,5 2015 MON-FRI
```